# Connect a password protected MS Access database file to Excel

Tags: excel, database, automation, connection

I want to create a password protected Access database to Excel file to save time and automate further process in excel.

Comment: This seems more suitable forum for your question: https://superuser.com/questions/1309052/how-to-import-password-protected-ms-access-tables-to-excel#1309058

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.